# Is it possible to get a GCM registration Id assigned to an Android device that isn't activated?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to make an app that would require two devices to communicate and am using two Android devices, one activated with Verizon, while the other is not activated. I am running code that gets a GCM registration id which successfully retrieves one on the activated device but does not do so on the other device. I assumed that an internet connection would be enough to qualify a device to receive a GCM registration id but it appears not to be the case. Can anyone please clarify this for me (and/or perhaps point me to something I might have failed to find online)?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to sign in to google play to get the  registration ID. I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCM is a Google Play service; it requires that both the Google Play APK and the Google Play services APK are installed on the device:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure

It's also helpful to add a quick check in your code to verify that the user has Google Play Services installed. Check out Google's explanation of it (with sample code):
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-play

Answer (score 1):

It requires devices running Android 2.2 or higher that also have the Google Play Store application installed, or or an emulator running Android 2.2 with Google APIs. However, you are not limited to deploying your Android applications through Google Play Store.

It uses an existing connection for Google services. For pre-3.0 devices, this requires users to set up their Google account on their mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on devices running Android 4.0.4 or higher.

Source: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html